# How to create NSDate timer with selector and time interval

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimer, nstimeinterval

Hi I want to create an NSDate object with the following functionality as the NSTimer line below.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(slider.value * 60) target:self selector:@selector(nextFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

So what is it that appeals to me about the above like is that I can put in the time I want for it to countdown. Also once the timer has reached 0 the nextFunction method is called. But I need to use NSDate for a future operation that cannot be completed with NSTimer. In summary, I want to create an NSDate that will countdown from whatever current value my slider holds then upon completion of countdown to call the nextFunction method. Thanks

Comment: unclear.. make it better add some pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the NSDate from the sliders value:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeintervalSinceNow:(slider.value * 60)];
```

Then use its timeInterval to create the timer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[date timeIntervalSinceNow] target:self selector:@selector(nextFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

I guess that should do it.

Comment: I have an event that can be triggered during the timer. How do I find out how much time has passed and store it in another object of NSDate?